# Ask correctly about something in the future : "Will candidates get accommodation ?"

Tags: questions, formal-language, future-time

I always find difficulties in asking properly in English. Can you help me to correct the following :

> Will the selected candidates for both fellowships get accommodation
>   and/or any financial support?

I have used the following form: **Will + subject + verb in infinitive**. Is this the correct grammar to ask about the future? Are there any other forms? The auxiliary "to do" is not needed to ask about the future?

Comment: We don't do "proofreading" here. If we don't address common grammar problems, then you'll just ask us to fix the next sentence, and the next one, and so on.  Plus, any answer is unlikely to help someone else with a similar problem.   So, again, please tell us which part of this sentence is giving you trouble, and any background or research you have done to make it correct.  Asking us to fix the entire sentence suggest you haven't done *any* research.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry for all the trouble, I wasn't aware of that rule. I have tried to include a specific question, please check if that makes sense. If not, please close the question. I am already kind of satisfied with the answer of Allen S

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "accommodations" rather than "accommodation",  "receive" instead of "get", and eliminating "and/or any financial support" in favor of "or financial support".

Merriam-Webster Dictionary defines accommodation:

1 : something supplied for convenience or to satisfy a need: such as
a : lodging, food, and services or traveling space and related services —**usually used in plural** (emphasis supplied) tourist accommodations on the boat, overnight accommodations.

There is nothing wrong with "get";  it's a perfectly respectable word, but there are people who object to it even when the usage is unobjectionable.  Many of these people are working in higher education, so to be safe you can use "receive" instead.

I think that and/or can be replaced easily by just "or" or just "and".  You actually have a number of possibilities here, because there are two potential fellowships and four options with each one (neither, just housing, just a stipend, both), so there are eight possibilities.  It's best to just ask if either provides accommodations and financial support, and expect that your correspondent to know to tell you which fellowship provides which benefits.

All that having been said, consider: "Will accommodations and a stipend be part of either of the two fellowships?"

Comment: Your answer is fine, but please see the site rules about "proofreading" questions.  We prefer avoiding answering questions that are likely to be closed.

Comment: I was aware that rule applied to the EL&U site, but I hadn't been aware it applied here.  Thanks for letting me know.